# Count first place in list of lists

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell at the university and I wonder if the function `countFirst` could be optimised? The task is to count the numbers on the first place (index 0)

- Input is a list of lists: the list has a fixed size of `n`
- Lists has a size of `m`
- The list contains numbers from `1..n`

e.g
input: `[[2,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]` --> result: `[1,2,0]` (Number one occurs once, number two occurs twice and so on)

or

input: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[3,2,1]]`--> result: `[2,0,2]` (Number one occurs twice, number two does not occur and so on)

My solution is:

```hs
countFirstPlace :: [[Int]] -> Int -> [Int]
countFirstPlace lists n = [ count x numbersOnFirstPlace | x <- [1..n]]
  where numbersOnFirstPlace = [head g  | g <- lists ]

count:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count n = foldr (\x -> if n == x then (+1) else id) 0
```

If the size n and m is bigger my solution will probably be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Haskell's optimization will do, but this solution sorts out the elements that have been searched already and thus may be a little faster for examples with large `m` and smaller `n`.

The function `separate` counts the elements that match the predicate `p`, and also returns all lists that do not. `forEachNumber` applies that to each `n` and also finishes after all elements have been counted. And `countFirstPlace` just starts that with `n=1`.

```
separate [] _ = (0,[])
separate (x:xs) p = let (cnt, rest) = separate xs p in 
                    if head x == p then (cnt+1, rest) else (cnt, x:rest)

forEachNumber [] _ = []
forEachNumber list p = let (cntCurrent, rest) = separate list p in
                       cntCurrent : forEachNumber rest (p+1)

countFirstPlace list = forEachNumber list 1
```